# How can I use a Google Apps Drive folder as a repository for website images

Tags: html, upload, google-drive-api

I'd like the following folder to be a repository for images for my domain:

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0ByX-7AGzNtLkfnJDcC0tRm5xcE9aYlp3akljS3p4OWxpeDNId0FlaEdONFVTak0xeld4NGc&usp=sharing

I've had no success despite having tried all the options suggested on SO.

- Gdriv.es says "Folder ID must be 28 characters long and can contain only letters, numbers, hyphen or underscore!"
- gdurl.com says my google drive links don't look like google drive urls
- http://googledrive.com/host/0ByX-7AGzNtLkfnJDcC0tRm5xcE9aYlp3akljS3p4OWxpeDNId0FlaEdONFVTak0xeld4NGc/ also does not work, getting errors like "The specified file is not an image. Please make sure you are linking directly to an image and not to the page it is on." and "The MIME type of the attached image is not supported." possibly because of the redirect.

It's a google apps drive account by the way and I need to be able to do stuff like  and upload files to Amazon.

Thanks very much!

Comment: I think the issue with the [http://googledrive.com/host/0ByX-7AGzNtLkfnJDcC0tRm5xcE9aYlp3akljS3p4OWxpeDNId0FlaEdONFVTak0xeld4NGc/854857003000/1.jpg](http://googledrive.com/host/0ByX-7AGzNtLkfnJDcC0tRm5xcE9aYlp3akljS3p4OWxpeDNId0FlaEdONFVTak0xeld4NGc/854857003000/1.jpg) style urls is that they redirect to a Google login screen if you're not already signed into Google.

Comment: Hmm yeah that's interesting, when I go to file links when not logged in I get a 401 error...maybe it's time to just move the whole thing to dropbox.

Comment: Is what you're trying to do basically using Google drive as a cheap CDN?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just messing around with the Gdriv.es service and the link you posted.  Thanks for sending me down the rabbit-hole...

Google Drive folders seem to either have 28 or 72 character long ids.  Most of your product subfolders have the 28 character id format.  Interestingly, there are some other folders that show up in your posted link that don't if you go in a different way to the same folder https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0ByX-7AGzNtLkfnJDcC0tRm5xcE9aYlp3akljS3p4OWxpeDNId0FlaEdONFVTak0xeld4NGc

Going through my own drive, what I'm seeing is that all of the older folders I have from 2009 and earlier have the 72 character id format.  Folders from 2012 are 28 character ids.  Unfortunately, I don't have anything in mine between summer 2009 and 2012.

A quick twitter search shows a [Dec 2012 tweet](https://twitter.com/vivekhaldar/status/275090459867635713) that kind of looks like an announcement.

My guess is there was some sort of API change with Google Drive from the 72 to the 28 character ids before then, and Gdriv.es doesn't support the old format.  Maybe if your root folder was created before that change, you could create a new root folder and shift your content over?

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer.

I just tried to make two new folders in two separate locations but I'm still getting 72 character long ids unfortunately.

Comment: Well, it was an interesting tangent to explore.  Doing not-officially-supported things is sort of a fun puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is that Google folders created after 2015 have more than 28 character long IDs.

You can instead just follow the link `googledrive.com/host/-INSERT ID HERE-` without the gdriv.es service.